# c# reading Hebrew text from console

Tags: c#, character-encoding, hebrew

I'm using windows 10 (maybe this is the problem:-) )

I have a simple code that reads text in Hebrew from console them print it's HEX\DEC value

but he give me 00 all the time 
on the console window I can see the Hebrew letters

any reason why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;

namespace HebTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static public void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Write your message here  - ");

            string StringMessage = Console.ReadLine();


            Console.WriteLine("print string  - " + StringMessage);
            ///message in HEX
            byte [] ByteMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(StringMessage);
            string HexMessage = BitConverter.ToString(ByteMessage); 

            Console.WriteLine("MSG in HEX -  " + HexMessage);
            Console.Write( 
                          Encoding.Default.GetString(ByteMessage)                   
                          );

            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (byte p in ByteMessage)
            {
                Console.Write((char)p + "  -  " +  p );
                Console.WriteLine("");


            }
```

}

for example I enter this  text 
"test אבגד"
and this is what I got :

```
Write your message here  -
test אבגד                         ---> this I wrote on the console
print string  - test
MSG in HEX -  74-65-73-74-20-00-00-00-00
test     
t  -  116
e  -  101
s  -  115
t  -  116
   -  32
   -  0
   -  0
   -  0
   -  0
```

what am I missing?

Thanks ,

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem: `byte [] ByteMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(StringMessage);`. What is your system default encoding, and can it handle Hebrew characters? What encoding do you *want* to see the result of? (Do you really want to use an encoding at all? What's the bigger goal here?)

Comment: 1. how do I know what is my system default encoding?  - I'm guessing it's Hebrew - but i don't know. you can see hebrew on the screen\on notepad\etc...   2. I want to be abel to see message\chars I have enter   3. the funny part is - it's work for me yesterday - then windows10 decided to reboot because of some stupid update - and today it didn't work..... so what to do\check?    ***** I looked at - clock&region--region setting--current system locale-- HEBREW , also beta: use Unicode UTF is marks

Comment: Rather than find out what `Encoding.Default` is, I would ask yourself what you're actually trying to achieve. What encoding do you *want* the result in? Do you need an encoding at all? Could you just print out the Unicode character numbers instead, without encoding the string as a `byte[]` at all?

Comment: I need to send the HEX vale to external device - this is why I need to see the right encoding .....

Comment: So what encoding is the external device expecting? For diagnostic purposes you could start by explicitly using `Encoding.UTF8`, but you really need to know what the device expects.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `Encoding.Default` to convert the string into binary. That's almost always a bad idea - it means the same code may work on some machines and not on others. It's pretty much *only* useful when you want to read/write a text file on that machine, and you're *sure* that the system default encoding is the right one to use for any machine that runs it. That's rare.

In particular, you're trying to talk to an external device - which means you need to use the encoding *it* expects. You should find that out, and use the appropriate encoding. For example, if the device expects UTF-8, use:

```
// Local variable names changed to be more idiomatic C#
string text = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

As you've now indicated that the device expects Windows-1255, that's code page 1255, so you get the encoding like this:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)
```

For clarify, I'd probably use a separate variable for that:

```
string text = Console.ReadLine();
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);
```

Comment: the external device is using "Windows-1255" - how do I use this there is no option for it in the Encoding.   ?

Comment: @David12123: You need `Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)` in this case, I believe.

Comment: (I've added that to my answer now.)

Comment: OK - didn't know I can do this :-) - it's working Thanks,      Now I want to read a text file - should I post a new question?I use  string Textmessage = File.ReadAllText(path) , the rest of the code is the same - but I get ?????? and not any Hebrew words

Comment: @David12123: Hint: look at the overloads to `File.ReadAllText`. But if that's not enough, then yes, ask as new question.

Comment: Ok - I see I need to use string StringMessage = File.ReadAllText(path1 , encoding);     and it's working .   I guess the encoding part you show me how to do really did the trick :-)       , so now - (just to be sure) on every computer this program should work ? even if it doesn't have Hebrew install? Thanks again so much!

Comment: @David12123: It would need to have the Windows-1255 encoding available, but I *suspect* that's almost always available. The machine definitely doesn't need to be set into a "Hebrew by default" or anything like that.

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem (after @Daisy Shipton let me think )

the code is OK 
need to go to 
 control Panel - region  - administrative - system locale -

**REMOVE V on Beta : use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support**

hope it will help someone someday

Comment: No, the code *isn't* okay. It's using the system default encoding, which is almost *never* the right thing to do, and won't be the right thing to do for your device. Instead, work out which encoding you *actually want to use* and set that explicitly.

Comment: OK - so tell me , how to make it work in Hebrew?  what I need to change ? where do I find the right encoding ? I know it should  be "windows-1255" - so what to do?  Thanks

Comment: See my reply on the comment on my answer.

Comment: @David12123 enabling UTF8 in the system locale will break stuff, including some Visual Studio extensions. There's a reason it's beta. Applications expect strings to be either Unicode or single-byte. It will take time for developers to discover which of their applications break with UTF8 as the default codepage