# Reading and Writing Hebrew string in C# on VS

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am building a Windows form C# application. And I need to read Hebrew text from Excel document and then do some stuff and then writing some Hebrew text to word document. Currently I failed to read Hebrew from Excel (I got question marks when printing it to console). I know that this problem relates to encoding issues.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace MLDRApplication
{
    public class ExcelReader
    {
        public static List<Customer> ExcelReadergetCustomers(string path)
        {
            List<Customer> customersList = new List<Customer>();
            //Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\fares\OneDrive\Documents\customersInitValues.xlsx");
            Excel.Worksheet customersWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];
            Excel.Worksheet laundryUnitsWorksheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[2];


            Excel.Range customersRange = customersWorksheet.UsedRange;
            Excel.Range laundryUnitsRange = laundryUnitsWorksheet.UsedRange;

            int customersSheetRowCount = customersRange.Rows.Count;
            int customersSheetColCount = customersRange.Columns.Count;
            int laundryUnitsSheetRowCount = laundryUnitsRange.Rows.Count;
            int laundryUnitsSheetColCount = laundryUnitsRange.Columns.Count;



            //iterate over the rows and columns and print to the console as it appears in the file
            //excel is not zero based!!
            for (int i = 1; i <= customersSheetRowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= customersSheetColCount; j++)
                {
                    //new line
                    if (j == 1)
                        Console.Write("\r\n");

                    //write the value to the console
                    //Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
                    if (customersRange.Cells[i, j] != null && customersRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                    {
                        //customersList.Add()
                        Console.Write(customersRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
                    }
                }

            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= laundryUnitsSheetRowCount; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= laundryUnitsSheetColCount; ++j)
                {
                    //new line
                    if (j == 1)
                        Console.Write("\r\n");

                    //write the value to the console
                    //Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
                    if (laundryUnitsRange.Cells[i, j] != null && laundryUnitsRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                    {
                        //customersList.Add()
                        Console.Write(laundryUnitsRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
                    }
                }

            }

            //cleanup
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
            //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
            //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

            //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(customersRange);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(customersWorksheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(laundryUnitsRange);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(laundryUnitsWorksheet);


            //close and release
            excelWorkbook.Close();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkbook);

            //quit and release
            excelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);

            return customersList;



        }
    }
}
```

I read this session [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51653551), but did not understand and get the right solution for this problem.

Comment: The console won't be able to print Hebrew characters as its encoding is far too limited. The VS debugger though should be able to show them correctly if you've made sure to convert them to the right encoding.

Comment: @double-beep No errors. just wrong printing(printing Hebrew as question marks ???). its something that relates to encoding.

Comment: @silkfire This is actually my real question. how i use encoding? where i need to add encoding in my source code? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not in the reading.
It's because console application default encoding does not support Hebrew.

At Console Application you can change the encoding adding the following line in the start of your code:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");
```

Edit: 
apparently

> You can't print Unicode characters in the console, it only supports
>   the characters that are available in the current code page. Characters
>   that are not available are converted to the closest equivalent, or a
>   question mark.

so you can do a small "hack" and just change the defualt output stream into a file:

```
   Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(File.Create("d:/your_output.txt"), Encoding.UTF8) { AutoFlush=true});
```

and by the end of the run it will write everything to there.

this is a **"quick and dirty"** solution for a permanent solution consider to use logging library as log4net.

Comment: I received "System.IO.IOException: 'The handle is invalid.". where i should insert the encoding in my src code?

Comment: Is it a console application project? @user8748472

Comment: Its not. its a form application (gui). still get the same exception. but i want to test my self by printing to console! by the way, what i need to add to my code for making sure that i will manage to write Hebrew from my form to word document?

Comment: and string in the end saved in memory as a byte array, how many bytes are representing one character and which one is answered by which encoding did you use. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_(Unicode_block)
you can read about unicode for example. 
just make sure that you are writing with an encoding that support hebrew and it will be fine.

Comment: hacks for the win